# Determinants: divisibility by 6 without remainder and $n\times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

1. Compute the determinant of \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & ...& n\\
    -1 & 0 & 3 & ...& n\\
     -1 & -2 & 0 & ...& n\\
   ...& ...& ...& ...& \\
   -1 & -2 & -3 & ...& n 
    \end{pmatrix}
   after some elementary raw operation, one can reach: 
   \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & ...& n\\
    -2 & -2 & 0 & ...& 0\\
   0& -2& -3& ...&0& \\
   ...& ...& ...& ...& \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1-n & n 
    \end{pmatrix}
   but I don't sure how to proceed.
2. Why the det. of the following matrix is divisible by 6 without remainder?
   \begin{pmatrix} 2^0 & 2^1 & 2^2 \\ 4^0 & 4^1 & 4^2\\ 5^0 & 5^1 & 5^2 \end{pmatrix}
   So I know that I have to show that its det. is divisible by $2$ and $3$, or equivalently that the sum of its digits divisible by $3$ and last digit is even. But I don't sure how to start the process.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see the pattern in the first matrix...

Comment: I guess it should be $(1,0,...,0,n)$ on the main diagonal, while beneath there are all negative (real numbers) and above all positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the first row to the other rows:
   $$
   \pmatrix{
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
   -1 & 0 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
   -1 & -2 & 0 & 4 & 5 \\
   -1 & -2 & -3 & 0 & 5 \\
   -1 & -2 & -3 & -4 & 5 \\
   }
   \to
    \pmatrix{
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    0 & 2 & * & * & * \\
    0 & 0 & 3 & * & * \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & * \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\times 5 \\
   }
   $$
   So the determinant is $2(n!)$.
2. The matrix is a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and its determinant is $(4-2)(5-2)(5-4)=6$.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding (2), you can reduce the matrix $A$ modulo $2$ to obtain

$$ A' = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Clearly, $\det(A') = 0$ which shows that $\det(A) \mod 2 = \det(A') = 0$. Similarly, reducing $A$ modulo 3, we obtain

$$ A'' = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

and this implies that $\det(A) \mod 3 = \det(A'') = 0$ which shows that $\det(A)$ is divible by both two and three.

Comment: Can you please give more details on the process of modulo reduction? (For instance, only for $A'$). Thank you!

Comment: Consider the definition of the determinant as a sum of products. If you think about it, to calculate $\det A \mod n$, you can either calculate $\det A$ and then do the modulo or you can reduce each element in $A$ and calculate the determinant as a matrix in $M_k(\mathbb{Z}_n)$. The fact that the answers are the same follows from the general properties of modulo with respect to sum and product.